# EV3 Brick and Commander app Bluetooth disconnecting

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, bluetooth, ios, commander

On iOS on an iPad, we're having an issue with the EV3 Brick and Commander app Bluetooth connection constantly disconnecting. The brick just stops responding, so we turn the brick off to disconnect and then reconnect Bluetooth via the app. After doing this it connects for a brief time, we're able to control the brick for a moment but very soon it disconnects again.

The app works just fine from an iPhone. So I'm assuming it's something to do with the app or Bluetooth on the iPad.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: Are you using iOS? Does the iOS setting on the EV3 match what you are using (turned *on* if you *are* using iOS, turned *off* if you are using anything else)?

Comment: Yes, using the IOS app - yes that matches.

Comment: Is it shutting down when it disconnects?